# Can I create white list for Azure Web App service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have web api and SQL Server VM.  I would like to configure inbound of virtual network so that TCP port 80 traffic is allowed only from Web API, but how?

Is it really so must to add (automatically) 50+ IP address to Inbound rules of Network security group to allow Any access to 1433?

Comment: Do you mean you want to open port 1433 to other server, not only web api?

Comment: VNET integration + only allow P2S VPN address space could work

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I would like to post SOAP request to VM and the Web API is sending the SOAP request,current rules prevent all 80 traffic from all source